# dataTable takes more time loading after logging into the client side

Tags: php, datatable

I have a dataTable where I show about the contracts in the index page once we logged in. The dataTable contains merely 2000 rows for now. I have tried to load it faster by reading some of the techniques like **deferRender, deferLoading, pagination, lengthChange and scroller**. But none of these seems to be helping me. But if I try with the **serverSide** property my **order by** conditions are not getting applied from mysqli database. Here is my dataTable code and my mysqli code.

dataTable:

```
jQuery("#table_contract").dataTable({
                    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'Bftri>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>",
                    "sAjaxSource": "mydatabase_source.php",
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    select: true,
                    buttons: [{
                                extend: 'collection',
                                text: 'Export',
                                buttons:[
                                            {
                                                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPDF</i>',
                                                titleAttr: 'PDF'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEXCEL</i>',
                                                titleAttr: 'Excel'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCSV</i>',
                                                titleAttr: 'CSV'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                                text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCOPY</i>',
                                                titleAttr: 'Copy'
                                            }
                                    ]
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                    }
                    ] });
```

I encode the data's to the dataTable using **json_encode($results)**.

Comment: loading time are depends on certain things like as you are loading more image in dataTable , huge details in db table that consume time, or else you are including online plugin source in JS-script.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a huge data set, or you are loading things like images in your rows, the way to go is the DataTables server-side processing.

About the ordering issue, you should use the [order parameter](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) to build your server-side query (you can look at [this](http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-dom-php-ajax-mysql-datasources/) and [this](http://phpflow.com/php/datatable-pagination-sorting-and-search-server-side-phpmysql-using-ajax/) tutorial)

I show you an example (based on the first tutorial link) with enabled ordering and filtering:

MySQL data:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` mediumint,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (1,"Cameron Pugh","1-287-272-8335","tempus.eu@nunc.co.uk","Germany","399235"),(2,"Giacomo Cross","1-748-121-3694","id@scelerisque.com","Brazil","3734"),(3,"Chadwick Pennington","1-622-974-0042","et@neque.org","Seychelles","48538"),(4,"Isaiah Dawson","1-782-569-0750","eu.eros.Nam@faucibus.com","Zimbabwe","10902"),(5,"Justin Collier","1-990-947-4684","Nunc.ut.erat@Vestibulum.co.uk","New Zealand","5483"),(6,"Clayton Hines","1-100-279-3148","Cras@vitae.com","Hungary","NR33 4KU"),(7,"Kane Carey","1-254-416-8972","Fusce@vulputate.org","Gibraltar","9587NU"),(8,"Vincent Gould","1-628-187-2689","aptent.taciti.sociosqu@metusIn.org","British Indian Ocean Territory","548135"),(9,"Hayes Page","1-383-950-0401","Donec@feliseget.com","Somalia","68-941"),(10,"Charles Irwin","1-402-205-9063","urna.Nullam@Pellentesqueultricies.com","Burundi","63-166");
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (11,"Brady Forbes","1-234-148-9372","In.faucibus.Morbi@porttitor.ca","Cuba","X8L 3P8"),(12,"Lucius Keller","1-754-272-5845","mauris@consectetueradipiscingelit.co.uk","Colombia","66-646"),(13,"Beck Robbins","1-225-415-3242","ipsum.dolor@nec.net","Cyprus","24633-242"),(14,"Stuart Rivers","1-576-527-1727","ridiculus.mus.Aenean@egestas.net","Armenia","809758"),(15,"Slade Zamora","1-421-103-8055","montes@Duisac.ca","Macao","67640"),(16,"Jameson Holder","1-677-759-2237","massa@lacusUt.ca","Spain","55890-580"),(17,"Howard Buck","1-199-819-6096","euismod@pellentesquemassa.com","South Sudan","17819"),(18,"Nero Coffey","1-198-687-1573","Vestibulum@blanditatnisi.com","Serbia","22297"),(19,"Forrest Williamson","1-590-612-9090","rhoncus.Nullam.velit@Donec.co.uk","Costa Rica","5033JC"),(20,"Gavin Holland","1-707-598-2034","volutpat.ornare@Integereu.co.uk","Denmark","4096");
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (21,"Zachery Finch","1-521-861-7870","mollis@Nullam.com","Slovenia","177715"),(22,"Kyle Pollard","1-876-829-9807","at@vel.ca","Botswana","P4E 7V4"),(23,"Lance House","1-995-534-0452","Curabitur.sed@nuncsedlibero.org","Cuba","G9L 8N0"),(24,"Neville Robbins","1-698-395-8194","pede@tempuslorem.net","Rwanda","5447"),(25,"Lance Winters","1-454-856-3279","consequat.dolor@tristiquesenectuset.com","Israel","6113"),(26,"Craig Willis","1-562-870-9056","In@Fusce.com","Guadeloupe","780057"),(27,"Jermaine Crosby","1-413-697-9562","magna@facilisi.com","Maldives","39378"),(28,"Ivor Donaldson","1-692-141-6383","mauris.sapien.cursus@habitant.org","Namibia","9026"),(29,"Jeremy Nunez","1-762-801-8582","mi.ac@eleifendvitaeerat.com","Nepal","24414"),(30,"Jasper Wong","1-423-632-0253","eget@ultrices.org","Barbados","P2Z 8K7");
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (31,"Jeremy Morgan","1-215-508-6736","mi.pede@ultricesiaculisodio.org","Qatar","89828"),(32,"Caldwell Crane","1-538-817-8691","amet@enimCurabiturmassa.net","Norfolk Island","64429-524"),(33,"Lyle Benton","1-821-536-5939","Morbi@porttitortellusnon.net","Malawi","29345"),(34,"Peter Foster","1-676-358-9027","et.tristique.pellentesque@eudolor.com","Uzbekistan","4209"),(35,"Malcolm Owen","1-730-651-5418","at.risus.Nunc@Curabitur.ca","Kyrgyzstan","329947"),(36,"Alden Berg","1-476-759-9158","massa@Phasellusdapibus.net","Mauritius","63981"),(37,"Arthur Reed","1-222-924-9018","sed.facilisis@odiovelest.net","Turkey","B3B 3W8"),(38,"Elvis Gregory","1-644-857-8387","eleifend.egestas@blandit.net","Armenia","1850"),(39,"Robert Edwards","1-379-321-4803","Praesent.eu@est.edu","South Africa","G9G 0K7"),(40,"Jerome Thompson","1-957-166-1255","montes@odiosemper.net","Guam","00298");
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (41,"Barclay Dominguez","1-151-678-7008","Nunc.mauris@facilisisvitae.com","Libya","226787"),(42,"Mason Maxwell","1-833-633-1289","Vivamus.sit.amet@dui.com","Sierra Leone","25196"),(43,"Forrest Fields","1-604-741-2880","Donec@nostraper.ca","Kenya","4599"),(44,"Dante Ryan","1-334-938-5185","Lorem.ipsum.dolor@nullaante.net","Belize","1645"),(45,"Clark Webb","1-789-916-3405","Maecenas.ornare.egestas@Namtempordiam.org","Belarus","01-636"),(46,"Chase Hood","1-217-256-0245","accumsan.neque.et@nullamagna.net","Suriname","75564"),(47,"Nasim Sargent","1-179-443-9947","Phasellus@mauriseu.com","Tonga","6208"),(48,"Ross Sanford","1-180-648-0200","vel.pede.blandit@vel.ca","Syria","17-417"),(49,"Denton Rowland","1-110-687-0329","enim.condimentum.eget@accumsaninterdumlibero.co.uk","Norfolk Island","Z5 9VX"),(50,"Branden Chang","1-154-713-7375","Aliquam@Ut.ca","Equatorial Guinea","5815");
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`country`,`zip`) VALUES (51,"George Gill","1-325-866-5545","non.magna@dictumProin.ca","Viet Nam","1475"),(52,"Hedley Cleveland","1-418-133-0843","ut.sem@ipsumnunc.co.uk","Monaco","77606"),(53,"Clayton Ellis","1-796-996-1413","a.feugiat.tellus@mauris.org","Papua New Guinea","403788"),(54,"Ivor Ramos","1-261-874-3568","elit@hendrerit.com","Australia","260263"),(55,"Malik Holt","1-837-382-3716","justo.eu@fermentum.net","Western Sahara","14540"),(56,"Mohammad Reese","1-321-170-6284","Aenean@ametfaucibusut.net","Denmark","5661"),(57,"Cameron Bryan","1-696-985-4867","scelerisque.lorem@arcuVestibulum.com","Haiti","99011"),(58,"Raphael Rodriquez","1-728-378-9772","est.Mauris@magna.ca","Benin","6061"),(59,"Simon Knox","1-725-880-2285","nunc.id@Nuncsollicitudin.co.uk","Belize","07313"),(60,"Damon Blevins","1-862-147-3498","luctus.lobortis@diamDuismi.net","Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","442151");
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="users" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PHONE</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>ZIP Code</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PHONE</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>ZIP Code</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#users').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    url: 'data.php',
                    type: 'POST'
                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "phone"},
                    {"data": "email"},
                    {"data": "country"},
                    {"data": "zip"}
                ],
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

data.php:

```
<?php  

// we need to check if there is a datatables post request
if (!empty($_POST) ) {

    // declaring database connection parameters
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbName = "datatablestest";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "********";
    $tableName = "tablename";

    // Create connection
    global $connection;
    $connection = $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

    function getData($sql){

        global $connection ; // we use connection already opened

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $row ) {
            $data[] = $row ;
        }
        return $data;
    }


    $draw = $_POST["draw"]; // counter used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // index of the sorting column (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record)
    $orderBy = $_POST['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data']; // Get name of the sorting column from its index
    $orderType = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // ASC or DESC
    $start  = $_POST["start"]; // Paging first record indicator.
    $length = $_POST['length']; // Number of records that the table can display in the current draw

    // count total records
    $recordsTotal = count(getData("SELECT * FROM $tableName "));


    /* SEARCH CASE : Filtered data
        if not empty, the user has input some data into the search field, so, we need to build a query to filter our data
     */
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['value'])){

        /* WHERE Clause for searching */
        for($i=0 ; $i<count($_POST['columns']);$i++){
            $column = $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'];// we get the name of each column using its index from POST request
            $where[]="$column like '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'";
        }
        $where = "WHERE ".implode(" OR " , $where);// id like '%searchValue%' or name like '%searchValue%' ....
        /* End WHERE */

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s", $tableName , $where);//Search query without limit clause (No pagination)

        $recordsFiltered = count(getData($sql));//Count of search result

        /* SQL Query for search with limit and orderBy clauses*/
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d ", $tableName, $where, $orderBy, $orderType, $start, $length);
        $data = getData($sql);
    }
    /* END SEARCH 
        if there is no data from the search field, we query from all records
    */
    else {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY %s %s limit %d , %d ", $tableName ,$orderBy,$orderType ,$start , $length);
        $data = getData($sql);

        $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;
    }

    $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
        "data" => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
}

?>
```

Comment: I have got 38 columns and 3000 rows in my datatable and if I'm using serverSide processing, then my order and where conditions gets collapsed.Let me check the 'this' link you provided.And is it possible to load data's according to page. If yes, please say how to using jquery datatTable

Comment: I have more than a table and I have used more joins and conditions. Would you please tell me how to use this method with such queries.(joins, where, orderBy, limit. these are given by me not from the datatable - structure)

Comment: @learner you just need to adapt the example query to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination 
[datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

Some example server side processing

```
$("#tablegridpost").dataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        "order": [[5, "desc"]],
        'ajax': '{{ path("post_list") }}',
        'columns': [
            {
                "orderable": true,
                "data": "postid"
            },..
```

You can see Ordering by column number

Comment: {{ path("post_list") }} - url for server side processing

Comment: Its not working, I get my conditions collapsed and even it shows the deleted data and it doesn't show the total records rather it shows 'NaN' and show items property doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

You can initially load small amount records like 250 and then upon page scroll you can append the new records

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function ()
    {
      if($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())
      {
      //ajax call for the new records
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the output cache in our page , then the data may be take the time at first request then we can read the data from the cache so this will take the optimum time to read the data from the cache ..

by this

[image]

[image]